# C++ code not producing output or running main

Tags: c++, hashtable

As the title says my code isnt producing any output. It is compiling and building with 0 errors but is not running. Here is my code.

I am trying to create a class defined hashtable and a array to compare search times.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class hashtable{
    private:
        int *p;
        int size;
    public:
        hashtable();
        ~hashtable();
        void insert(int n);
        int search(int n);

};

hashtable::hashtable(){
    size =50;
    p =new int[50];
    for (int i =0; i<size; i++){
        p[i] = -1;
    }

}

 hashtable::~hashtable(){
    delete [] p;
}

void hashtable::insert(int n){
    int key = n % size;

    while(p[key] == -1){
        if(p[key] ==n){ 
            break;
        }
        else{
            key = (key+1) % size;
        }
    }
    p[key]=n;
}

int hashtable::search(int n){

    int key = n%size;
    int comparisons =-1;

    while (p[key] != -1){
        if (p[key] ==n){
            return comparisons;
        }
        else{
            key = (key+1) %size;
            comparisons++;
        }
    }
    return comparisons;
}

int main(){
    cout <<"program start" <<endl;
    hashtable h;
    int S[50];

    for(int i; i<50;i++){
        S[i] = -1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<50 ; i++){
        int j = rand()%100;
        h.insert(j);
        S[i] = j;    
    }
    int k;
    int hashavg = 0;
    int arrayavg =0;
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){
        cout <<"Enter number to search: ";
        cin >> k;
        while(S[i]!=k){
            arrayavg++;
            i++;
        }
        hashavg = hashavg + h.search(k);

    }
    cout <<"Average comparisons of hash table: " <<double(hashavg) / 5 <<endl;
    cout <<"Average comparisons of array: " <<double(arrayavg) /5 <<endl;
}
```

I have tried to put a `cout` at the start of the `int main()` but that wont even output. Im not sure why it is doing this and Im unable to find a fix to this problem.

Comment: How are you compiling and running?

Comment: @ChrisMM I am using vscode and running in debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
void hashtable::insert(int n)
{
    int key = n % size;

    while(p[key] == -1)
    {
        if(p[key] ==n)
        { 
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            key = (key+1) % size;
        }
    }
    p[key]=n;
}
```

called from `h.insert(j);` with `j` going from 0 to 50.

```
    while(p[key] == -1)
    {
        if(p[key] ==n)
```

That second `if` cannot enter, because `p[key]` is `-1` but `n` is >= 0. So, your code is identical to:

```
void hashtable::insert(int n)
{
    int key = n % size;

    while(p[key] == -1)
    {
            key = (key+1) % size;
    }
    p[key]=n;
}
```

But, unless we get to `p[key]=n;`, all `p`s are -1. So, your code is identical to:

```
void hashtable::insert(int n)
{
    int key = n % size;

    while(true)
    {
    }
}
```

As such, it hangs by looping forever. You need to revisit your logic.